# Cryptography.ProtectedData CurrentUser with ASP.NET and Forms Authentication

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, encryption, forms-authentication

If encryption is used via ProtectedData CurrentUser and I have a site using Forms auth (with a custom membership module, don't think that will make a difference), will it work across several different web servers?

My guess would be that it would if the current user that is used is the User.Identity, 'cause that will be the logged in user, and will be the same on any web server.

The docs didn't seem to say anything about it working with ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "current user" will be the user the asp.net application is running as (not the user accessing the site).  Typically this is /ASPNET user account however it can be changed. You can verify this with the `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()` function.

Your other option is to use `DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine` to store it in the machine store instead (acceisslble from any account on the machine).  While this may seem less secure member if you are using an unprivileged account (like ASPNET user) than anyone could write an app to run as that user and gain access to that user store.

Comment: Ok, so unless it's running as a domain account, unprotect will only work on a single machine?

Comment: Yes.  The asp.net application can still store data for multiple users using the protect/unprotect functions.  for example you could pass the following string to protect "userid:392013 value:this is a secret".  Protect will return an encrypted string.  Storing that string in the database will ensure that it can ONLY be decrypted from the machine where it was encrypted. Just be aware as far as windows is concerned they are all the same windows user (ASPNET account) and thus will be stored in the same store.